# jquery validator addMethod question

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Working with JQuery Validator and just have a quick question.
I'm using addMethod to define a custom validation for Australian phone numbers based on a regex. This is a method that I'd like to use in multiple pages, so I want to define the function in an external .js file, and pop it into the addMethod call.

If I use:

```
$.validator.addMethod('phone', regexPhone(value), 'Please enter a valid phone number');
```

I get a reference error: can't find value, but if you build the function straight into the addMethod call, you use the parameter value.

Is there any way to add a reusable function into the call for addMethod?

Ta,
Ryan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.validator.addMethod('phone', regexPhone, 'Please enter a valid phone number');
```

The second parameter in addMethod is a callback, This will call the function regexPhone.

The way you did called the regexPhone function before appending in the callback.

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I saw your response, it made sense. Been fiddling with validator for the last 4 or 5 hours, so I'm a little bit frazzled! =)